# How can i replicate the 'ended' event on a looped HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

The 'ended' event does not seem to work for looped videos (attribute loop).

```
 <video id="video-player" width="946" height="503" preload="auto" loop="loop"  poster="" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

I would like to trigger an event when the video playback has ended for the first time in the loop.

I worked around this by checking if currentTime == duration on 'timeupdate' :

```
        var video = $("#video-player");
        video.on('timeupdate', function(e) {
          if (this.currentTime > this.duration - 0.1) {
            ... do things when playback finished for the first time
          }
        })
```

You can see im checking

> duration - 0.1

And this is because the currentTime never seems to reach the full duration value.
Right on the end of the playback and the next moment (when it restarts the loop) currentTime is 0 (zero)

Is there a better way?
I know i can cause the loop with some extra js and have the 'ended' event available but the loop attribute is required in this case

Comment: Please post your HTML snippet of your video element.

Answer (score 4):

If your html element has a attribute called `loop`, you have to remove it. Even if you have written something like `<video loop="false">`.

**Update**

If the loop attribute exists on your element, the ended-event will never be fired!
I would recommend you to loop the video manually and remove the loop attribute.
According to your comment, you need to loop it after the first time.
Maybe you can make it like this:

```
$("#video-player").each(function () {
  this.onended = function (e) {
    //Do whatever you want

    this.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i need the loop attribute and i also need to capture the end of the first loop, the loop attribute cannot go away - it is required for my case

Answer (score 1):

Two recommondations:

- Use Vanillebärs idea, but on the first `onended`-Event add your `loop`- attribute via js
- increase your `0.1` value. the `currentTime` intervall is irregular! It could be, that it is not thrown within your 100ms. check if it works with `1.0` (1sec). But If you wanna make sure the video is really watch to the end, you have to use `onended`

Comment: indeed, have noticed that irregularity!
increased to .5 which seems to be quite safe, thanks